# Insert html in jade through res.render

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

Having a little problem with inserting pure html into Jade.
I store html-formatted text in db. And router takes these data and sends to the jade template.
For the moment the output html i recieve is:

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
```

In jade template i get data in this way:

```
| #{content}
div #{content2}
```

And the router send it this way:

```
admin.query("SELECT * FROM `Article` WHERE `ArticleId` = " + req.params.id + ";", function (err, data) {
        res.render('static.jade', {
            'title'      : data[0].ArticleTitle,
            'page_title' : data[0].ArticleTitle,
            'content'    : data[0].ArticleContent,
            'content2'   : data[0].ArticleContent
        });
    });
```

I hope there is the way to fix it. That's gonna be big problem storing jade-formatted text in db. Regards for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `!{ variable }` to include unescaped content.

So:

```
| !{content}
div !{content2}
```

See more [here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/).